# How to make an object be sensed if it is No Collision in BGE

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, collision

I am making a space game, but I need to make a boundary. I have four cubes and I'm using a property sensor to detect them and then display text, but I don't want the spaceship to collide with them and when set the physics type to "No Collision", the ship doesn't sense the boarder. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable "Ghost" on the object to be sensed (Properties/Physics/Physics)